# ¿Cómo realizar una consulta SQL búscando dos nombres de un mismo campo?

Tags: sql

Estoy intentando hacer una consulta SQL en la que pueda buscar una palabra dentro de un campo, en este caso quiero que busqueda si contiene X y Z por ejemplo, este es mi consulta SQL.,

```
SELECT * FROM articulos WHERE seccion LIKE '%Publication Only: Gastrointestinal Cancer—Colorectal and Anal%' AND seccion LIKE 'Gastrointestinal Cancer—Colorectal and Anal' ORDER BY articulo_id DESC
```

¿Cómo podría realizar esta consulta buscando dos palabras?

Comment: ¿Qué tipo de dato es la columna donde guardaste ese texto?, además ayudaría mucho si especificas ¿qué motor de bases de datos usas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Es muy parecido a lo que tú has puesto...desconozco que es lo que estas buscando pero es algo a esto. Si quieres buscar X y Z en un campo, la consulta es:

```
SELECT * FROM articulos WHERE seccion LIKE '%X%' AND seccion LIKE '%Z%' ORDER BY articulo_id DESC
```

Si quieres buscar la palabra "Cancer-Colorectal" y "Anal" en un mismo campo, seria asi:

```
SELECT * FROM articulos WHERE seccion LIKE '%Cancer—Colorectal%' AND seccion LIKE '%Anal%' ORDER BY articulo_id DESC
```

y si quisieras buscar al menos una de esas 2 palabras la consulta sería asi:

```
SELECT * FROM articulos WHERE seccion LIKE '%Cancer—Colorectal%' OR seccion LIKE '%Anal%' ORDER BY articulo_id DESC
```

Espero te sirva

Comment: Muchísimas @Emilio Torres !!